Group rows which share some value in three columns and assign them a same id
I have an issue on SQL Server. I have a table similar to this example:



RegisterId
Name
Phone
Email




XXX-00001
John Strauss
241567
Null


XXX-00023
Rick Astley
241567
richardastley@gmail.com


XXX-00003
John Strauss
NULL
NULL


XXX-00099
NULL
241567
georgeharrison@gmail.com


XXX-00085
NULL
256819
richardastley@gmail.com


XXX-00016
NULL
NULL
georgeharrison@gmail.com


XXX-00007
John Deep
280933
NULL


XXX-00008
John Deep
93484
NULL


XXX-00009
Javier Estrada
94578
javier@gmail.com



You can notice I have duplicated values. It's because they correspond to the same user. This happen cause the values can come from different many dbs.
I would like to assign them a new ID to identify them as the same user (as it should be) if they have:

same phone
same name
same e-mail

Something like this:



RegisterId
Name
Phone
Email
UserId




XXX-00001
John Strauss
241567
Null
1


XXX-00023
Rick Astley
241567
richardastley@gmail.com
1


XXX-00003
John Strauss
NULL
NULL
1


XXX-00099
NULL
241567
georgeharrison@gmail.com
1


XXX-00085
NULL
256819
richardastley@gmail.com
1


XXX-00016
NULL
NULL
georgeharrison@gmail.com
1


XXX-00007
John Deep
280933
NULL
2


XXX-00008
John Deep
93484
NULL
2


XXX-00009
Javier Estrada
94578
javier@gmail.com
3



I have tried many functions in SQL, even some CTE's but I just can't find a way to achieve it. Could someone please give me an idea of which approximation should I use to solve this problem?
dbFiddle

This is interesting, because Rick Astley and John Strauss are very clearly two different people. I'd go as far as saying 00007 John Deep and 0008 John Deep are clearly two different people, given they have different phone numbers; they just happen to share the same name. You could convince me 00023 and 00085 are the same person, though, as are 00099 and 00016.

@JoelCoehorn That may be true that his rules could use some adjustment, but it is the ground rules of the question. For all we know this is a concrete, but hypothetical example-used to ask the simplified question-and we shouldn't confuse the example for the question.

For example, there could be a typo when entering data: Xavier Estrada  and
Javier Estrada

Consider query1. This option depends on the grouping order and may produce an ambiguous result. As a result of grouping, we lose some of the data, which can lead to an incorrect result. However, as an idea, it will do for a start.
Four steps
1.Group by name. We join (condense to) all rows with the same name.
2.Group previous output by phone. We join (condense to) all rows with the same phone or name.
3.Group previous output by email. We join (condense to) all rows with the same email or phone or name.
This query result is condensed rowset, where rows have same phone or same name or same e-mail or phone or name.
On each step we aggregate RegisterId's for rows - regids.
4.Join this result with target table, where target table RegisterId contains in regids.
See example
with t1 as(
  select min(registerid)registerid,name,min(phone)phone,min(email) email
     ,string_agg(registerid,',') regids
  from registers
  group by name
)
,t2 as(
  select min(registerid)registerid,min(name)name,phone,min(email) email
     ,concat(string_agg(regids,',') ,',',string_agg(registerid,',')) regids
  from T1
  group by phone
)
,t3 as(
  select min(registerid)registerid,min(name)name,min(phone)phone,email
     ,concat(string_agg(regids,','),',',string_agg(registerid,',')) regids
     ,row_number()over(order by min(registerid)) newuserId
  from T2
  group by email
)
update registers
  set userid=newuserid
from registers rg
left join t3 on rg.registerid=t3.registerid
  or ( ','+t3.regids+',' like '%,'+rg.registerid+',%' ) 
;

Output is



RegisterID
Name
Phone
Email
UserId




XXX-00001
John Strauss
241567
null
1


XXX-00003
John Strauss
null
null
1


XXX-00016
null
null
georgeharrison@gmail.com
1


XXX-00023
Rick Astley
241567
richardastley@gmail.com
1


XXX-00085
null
256819
richardastley@gmail.com
1


XXX-00099
null
241567
georgeharrison@gmail.com
1


XXX-00007
John Deep
280933
null
2


XXX-00008
John Deep
93484
null
2


XXX-00009
Javier Estrada
94578
javier@gmail.com
3



Demo
The same idea, but the result is unambiguous. Here we do not lose data and grouping through window functions gives us the correct result.
update registers
  set userid=newuserid
from registers rg
left join (
  select * ,dense_rank()over(order by id3)newuserid
  from (
     select * ,min(id2)over(partition by coalesce(email,registerid))id3
     from (
       select * ,min(id1)over(partition by coalesce(phone,registerid))id2
       from (
          select * ,min(id0)over(partition by coalesce(name,registerid))id1
          from (
             select * ,row_number()over(order by registerid) id0
             from registers
         )t0
       )t1
     )t2
  ) t3
)t4 on rg.registerid=t4.registerid

Demo
Subquery result for update id



RegisterID
Name
Phone
Email
UserId
id0
id1
id2
id3
newuserid




XXX-00001
John Strauss
241567
null
1
1
1
1
1
1


XXX-00003
John Strauss
null
null
1
2
1
1
1
1


XXX-00016
null
null
georgeharrison@gmail.com
1
6
6
6
1
1


XXX-00023
Rick Astley
241567
richardastley@gmail.com
1
7
7
1
1
1


XXX-00085
null
256819
richardastley@gmail.com
1
8
8
8
1
1


XXX-00099
null
241567
georgeharrison@gmail.com
1
9
9
1
1
1


XXX-00007
John Deep
280933
null
2
3
3
3
3
2


XXX-00008
John Deep
93484
null
2
4
3
3
3
2


XXX-00009
Javier Estrada
94578
javier@gmail.com
3
5
5
5
5
3



Upd1.
I want to keep in my answer the example given by
shawnt00 in the comment and by the link. Despite the fact that the probability of such a side effect for this task is very small, and it is possible to replace in expression coalesce(...,registerid))  RegisterId to any Guid, the example seemed useful and instructive to me.
Thanks again to @shawnt00.
There could be collisions across the columns (name='XXX-00010' and RegisterId='XXX-00010')
INSERT INTO Registers (RegisterID, Name, Phone, Email)
VALUES
( 'XXX-00085', 'XXX-00010',             '256819', 'richardastley@gmail.com'  ),
( 'XXX-00016', NULL,             'XXX-00010',     'georgeharrisonXX@gmail.com' ),
( 'XXX-00010', null, null, null)


The last query is very good. I do see an unlikely kind of scenario where it would fail though if there could be collisions across the columns: https://dbfiddle.uk/henBvX_x

Thank you.An interesting example. I hope such collisions are incredible. But only the OP can answer this question. I'm guessing RegisterId won't look like a phone or mailing address. We can be sure about the mailing address.

There can always be conflicts, and depending on the user you start with you can get different groupings of users, but here's my attempt:
--Pick one user
DECLARE @name varchar(200);
SET @name = (SELECT TOP(1) Name FROM Registers WHERE Name IS NOT NULL AND UserID IS NULL);
WHILE @name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT '@name: '+@name;

    --Get the next available UserID for this user
    DECLARE @nextUserID int    = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(UserID), 0)+1 FROM Registers WHERE UserID IS NOT NULL);
    PRINT '   @nextUserID: int = '+CAST(@nextUserID AS varchar);

    -- Give the user their new userID
    UPDATE Registers SET UserID = @nextUserID WHERE UserID IS NULL AND Name = @name;

    --Keep looking for other rows that match this user in some way
    DECLARE @rc int = 1;
    WHILE @rc > 0 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Registers 
        SET UserID = @nextUserID 
        WHERE UserID IS NULL 
        AND (
            Name  IN (SELECT Name  FROM Registers WHERE UserID = @nextUserID)
            OR
            Phone IN (SELECT Phone FROM Registers WHERE UserID = @nextUserID)
            OR
            Email IN (SELECT Email FROM Registers WHERE UserID = @nextUserID)
        )
        SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;
        PRINT '   Rows updated: @rc='+CAST(@rc AS varchar);
        --SELECT * FROM Registers
    END

    SET @name = (SELECT TOP(1) Name FROM Registers WHERE Name IS NOT NULL AND UserID IS NULL);
END

SELECT * FROM Registers
ORDER BY UserID;

Giving results:
| RegisterID | Name           | Phone  | Email                    | UserID |
|------------|----------------|--------|--------------------------|--------|
| XXX-00001  | John Strauss   | 241567 | null                     | 1      |
| XXX-00003  | John Strauss   | null   | null                     | 1      |
| XXX-00016  | null           | null   | georgeharrison@gmail.com | 1      |
| XXX-00023  | Rick Astley    | 241567 | richardastley@gmail.com  | 1      |
| XXX-00085  | null           | 256819 | richardastley@gmail.com  | 1      |
| XXX-00099  | null           | 241567 | georgeharrison@gmail.com | 1      |
| XXX-00007  | John Deep      | 280933 | null                     | 2      |
| XXX-00008  | John Deep      | 93484  | null                     | 2      |
| XXX-00009  | Javier Estrada | 94578  | javier@gmail.com         | 3      |

@name: John Strauss
   @nextUserID: int = 1
   Rows updated: @rc=2
   Rows updated: @rc=2
   Rows updated: @rc=0
@name: John Deep
   @nextUserID: int = 2
   Rows updated: @rc=0
@name: Javier Estrada
   @nextUserID: int = 3
   Rows updated: @rc=0

dbFiddle

This tries to map out all the linkages as a graph. There are probably some improvements to make so it can take advantage of transitivity. I'm trying to get better at graph traversals so I figured it was still worth sharing:
with matches as (
    select r1.RegisterID as id1, r2.RegisterID as id2
    from Registers r1 left outer join Registers r2
        on r2.RegisterID >= r1.RegisterID
           and (r2.Name = r1.Name or r2.Phone = r1.Phone or r2.Email = r1.Email)
), r as (
    select 1 as level, id1, id2,
        cast(concat('>', id1, '>', id2) as varchar(max)) as chain
    from matches
    union all
    select level + 1,
        case when r.id2 = m.id1 then r.id1 else least(r.id1, m.id1) end,
        case when r.id2 = m.id1 then m.id2 else greatest(r.id1, m.id1) end,
        concat(chain, '>', case when r.id2 = m.id1 then m.id2 else concat('(', r.id1, '>', m.id1, '>)') end)
    from r inner join matches m on r.id2 in (m.id1, m.id2)
    where chain not like concat('%>', case when r.id2 = m.id1 then m.id2 else m.id1 end, '>%')
)
select distinct
    coalesce(id2, id1) as RegisterId,
    dense_rank() over (order by id1) as UserId
from r r1
where r1.id2 is null or not exists (
    select 1 from r r2
    where r2.id1 <> r2.id2 and r2.id2 = r1.id1
)
order by UserId, RegisterId;

https://dbfiddle.uk/lbwcz26a
