How to write a SQL query to group accounts that share same phone numbers directly or indirectly in recursive way?
I am trying to group a list of accounts if they share same phone numbers directly or indirectly using SQL query in recursive way. I was trying traversing the parent-child hierarchy like most SQL recursive examples do, but it doesn't work because each parent in my case could have multiple children. I am expecting the query to return all three accounts within the same group.
e.g.
AccountID   PhoneNumber
1           1111111111
1           2222222222
2           1111111111
2           4444444444
3           3333333333
3           4444444444

I have tried common approach to this recursive problem in SQL by defining base case and recursive case, but I am getting "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion." error.
-- Step 1: Define a recursive CTE to find connected components
WITH ConnectedAccounts AS (
    -- Base case: Select each account and its direct connections
    SELECT 
        a.AccountID AS RootAccount,
        a.AccountID,
        a.PhoneNumber,
        level = 0
    FROM 
        AccountPhoneNumbers a
    
    UNION ALL
    
    -- Recursive case: Connect accounts sharing a phone number
    SELECT 
        c.RootAccount,
        b.AccountID,
        b.PhoneNumber,
        c.level + 1
    FROM 
        AccountPhoneNumbers b 
        JOIN ConnectedAccounts c ON b.PhoneNumber = c.PhoneNumber
    WHERE 
        b.AccountID <> c.AccountID  -- Prevent looping back to the same account
),

-- Step 2: Select distinct groupings from the recursive result
DistinctGroups AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        RootAccount,
        AccountID
    FROM
        ConnectedAccounts 
)

-- Step 3: Aggregate accounts into groups based on their connected root account
SELECT
    RootAccount,
    STRING_AGG(AccountID, ',') AS ConnectedAccounts
FROM
    DistinctGroups 
GROUP BY
    RootAccount


Here's one way to detect cycles. https://dbfiddle.uk/h-A0AM9d

Thanks for the reply! There's no path including all account ids, (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4) in your example.

I answered a similar question yesterday although I'm not certain my solution is very efficient. FWIW I've adapted it to your data and it does seem to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/Eub0a2Kp (See question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78410258/group-rows-which-share-some-value-in-three-columns-and-assign-them-a-same-id/)

Awesome! Your second code example works very well. Can you share the link to the question you answered yesterday? I just want to learn the idea of this logic. To me, writing complex recursion logic using T-SQL is a bit challenging.

It's in that earlier comment. You'll see that there were two other answers that might even work better. I tried one of them though and I think it failed on your data because of the 1:M relationship.

Does this answer your question? How can I combine Group Identifiers into Single Group?

@siggemannen In your example, the number of identifiers for each id is fixed to 3. In my example, the number of phone number for each account could vary a lot from 1 to many. How can I write the logic to handle that? Thanks!

No, it's just that identifiers are in multiple columns and rows. The logic just unpivots them before landing at your problem

@siggemannen If I just unpivot your dataset into separate rows for each ID, your original query is not working. Can you help me out on this? Otherwise, I will have to pivot my dataset to one row for each ID. Thanks!

I'm not sure what you mean, but i took the code from the answer and just pasted your data and changed the columns and got the result: https://dbfiddle.uk/MkyRgscA

@siggemannen I was referring to the code from "Creating a single ID for any combination of matches between three different identifiers" post. The above code is working, but when I run that code against 1 million accounts with over 1 million phone numbers in total, the query didn't complete even after 3 hours, which is not acceptable for our business requirement. I think that the ultimate solution is to store account to phone relations in graph database model, then query it. Am I correct?

Well, do you have index on phone numbers, since that's the matching stuff? I actually took the code from another answer so nevermind that :) I'll fix a new version with the WHILE loop

@siggemannen I have index on phone numbers in the underlying phone table. But you are using CTE, so I am not sure that CTE would utilize the index. Should I switch that CTE to temp table with creating index on phone number column?

Here's a couple of versions.
The graph (might be slow):
with 
    nodes as (
v(grp)
    select accountid as id, phonenumber as grp
    from
    (
        VALUES  (1, 1111111111)
        ,   (1, 2222222222)
        ,   (2, 1111111111)
        ,   (2, 4444444444)
        ,   (3, 3333333333)
        ,   (3, 4444444444)
        ,   (4, 11111111113)
        ,   (5, 11111111113)
        ,   (5, 1111111111)
    ) t (AccountID,PhoneNumber)

    ),
    edges as (
        select distinct n1.id as id1, n2.id as id2
        from nodes n1
        inner join nodes n2 on n1.grp = n2.grp
    ),
    rec as (
        select id1, id2, cast(id1 as nvarchar(max)) as visited from edges
        union all
        select r.id1, e.id2, concat(r.visited, ',', e.id2)
        from rec r
        inner join edges e on e.id1 = r.id2
        where concat(',', r.visited, ',') not like concat('%,', e.id2, ',%')
    ),
    fin as (
        select id1, min(value) min_id
        from rec r
        cross apply string_split(r.visited, ',')
        group by id1
    )
select id1 as id, dense_rank() over(order by min_id) grp
from fin f

The loop (probably needs index on phone):
SELECT  AccountID AS ID, PhoneNumber AS Number, CAST(NULL AS INT) AS ID_To
INTO #t
FROM
(
        VALUES  (1, 1111111111)
        ,   (1, 2222222222)
        ,   (2, 1111111111)
        ,   (2, 4444444444)
        ,   (3, 3333333333)
        ,   (3, 4444444444)
        ,   (4, 11111111113)
        ,   (5, 11111111113)
        ,   (5, 1111111111)
        ,   (6, 4444444444)
        ,   (7, 3333333333)
        ,   (8, 13)
        ,   (8, 7)
        ,   (8, 3)
        ,   (9, 13)
        ,   (10, 14)
    ) t (AccountID,PhoneNumber)

-- Create index on Number

WHILE @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE  t3
    SET ID_TO = x.ID_to
    FROm    (   
        SELECT  t2.ID, ID_to = MIN(ISNULL(t.ID_To, t.ID))
        FROM    #t t
        INNER JOIN #t t2
            ON  ISNULL(t.id_To, t.id) < ISNULL(t2.ID_to, t2.id)
            AND t.Number = t2.Number
            AND t.ID <> t2.ID
        GROUP BY t2.ID
        ) x
    INNER JOIN #t t3 -- Update ALL rows to the lowest value
        ON  t3.ID = x.ID
END

-- See created groups
SELECT  ISNULL(ID_TO, ID) AS groups
FROM    #t
GROUP BY ISNULL(ID_TO, ID)


The loop version is way fast, and it only takes 30 seconds to finish the matching process against over 1 million accounts. You are a genius! THANK YOU!
